# How to show $V= W+W^{\bot}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

> Let $W$ be a subspace of a finite-dimensional vector space $V$. How can we show $V= W+W^{\bot}$?

$ W+W^{\bot} \subset V$ is trivial, but the other direction is not that obvious.

Comment: What is $V$? Is it (finite-dimensional) Euclidean space? An arbitrary Hilbert space?

Comment: @TheoBendit Thank you for pointing that out. It is of finite dimension.

Comment: And would that be $\Bbb{R}^n$ or $\Bbb{C}^n$? Or an arbitrary finite-dimensional inner product space?

Comment: @TheoBendit What's the difference between $\mathbb R^n$ and $\mathbb C^n$ in this question?

Comment: Not too much. In terms of answering, it'll come down to a question of notation (in particular, using the dot product would be appropriate for $\Bbb{R}^n$, but not $\Bbb{C}^n$). However, this is more of a general caution about writing your questions. They should be relatively self-contained, with the context in the question itself. It shouldn't be left to us to guess, from your use of the $\perp$ symbol, that there's some kind of inner product structure on the space, or guess whether you've heard the term "inner product" before or not!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's suppose that $\dim W = m$ and $\dim V = n$.

Take a basis for $W$ first. It is well-known that it can be expanded to a basis for $V$. Now use the Gram-Schmidt process on this basis to obtain an orthonormal basis for $V$ such as $\{b_1, \cdots, b_n\}$. Then $\{b_1,\cdots,b_m\}$ is a basis for $W$ and $\{b_{m+1}, \cdots, b_{n}\}$ is a basis for $W^{\perp}$.

Comment: It's a fine hint for the case where $\operatorname{dim} W = 1$, but I'm not sure it's clear (to someone who doesn't know the answer) how this would lead to a general argument.

Comment: If you project onto an orthogonal basis, you can add the projections to form a projection onto the entire subspace. But, your answer is flawed in that, $v - \operatorname{proj}_x(v)$ is perpendicular to $x$ (which isn't quite what you've said, but that's another issue), but that doesn't imply $v - \operatorname{proj}_x(v) \in W^\perp$, as you haven't established orthogonality with **all** vectors in $W$.

Comment: I'm afraid it is still flawed, yes. It's not clear what you're actually doing with the projections here. I *think* you're wanting to subtract them from $v$, but all you seem to be doing is subtracting the (unscaled) $x$ from the (unprojected) $v$. This will not give you the orthogonal component that I think you want. Further, it's not actually correct to find the orthogonal components individually. You need to sum the projections, and subtract them off $v$, i.e. $$v - \sum_i (v \cdot e_i) e_i.$$ This vector is orthogonal to all the orthonormal vectors $e_i$.

Comment: @TheoBendit Yeah. It worked if I assumed my basis for $W$ to be orthonormal and expanded each vector $w \in W$ in that basis but the calculation became long and typing it in LaTeX was becoming a headache. So, I decided to switch to a less intuitive, but cleaner proof. :D Even though the other proof was prettier because it had a geometric taste. xD

Answer (score 0):

Since perp is used so we are in innerproduct space. Let $x\in V$ then there exists a unique $y\in W$ s.t. $||x-y||\le ||x-z||,\forall z\in W$ and $x-y \perp W$. Set $r=x-y$ then $x=y+r$ where $y\in W,r\in W^\perp$. So $x\in W+W^\perp$. More over due to uniqueness you can replace plus by direct sum.